# Why does $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id(); return 0?

Tags: wp-query

The code below returns `0` for pages on the frontend.

```
/**
 * @uses WP_Query
 * @uses get_queried_object()
 * @see get_the_ID()
 * @return int
 */
function get_the_post_id() {
  if (in_the_loop()) {
       $post_id = get_the_ID();
  } else {
       global $wp_query;
       $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
         }
  return $post_id;
}

$page_id = get_the_post_id();
echo $page_id;
```

Comment: If you're just running `get_the_post_id();` in functions.php outside the function then it's too early and the queried object hasn't been determined yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Plugins and themes are loaded pretty early in WordPress's lifecycle](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request). Assuming this code is a plugin file or a theme's `functions.php` file, then it is executing before WordPress has set up the query, or even parsed the arguments in the request. The queried object ID is `0` because no query has taken place yet :)

Try running the code in a hook after WordPress has finished executing the main query instead:

```php
function wpse408763_test() {
  echo get_the_post_id();
}

add_action( 'wp', 'wpse408763_test' );
```

It's worth mentioning that `WPDB::get_queried_object_id()` can return values which do not correspond to a post at all - on a taxonomy term archive page, it will be the ID of the term, for example, which would result in the `get_the_post_id()` function returning a term ID when used outside the loop but the current post's ID within the loop. You might want to consider only returning the value from `get_queried_object_id()` in the case of `is_single() || is_page()` and perhaps `false` otherwise in order to mitigate some headaches down the road.

There's also a [global wrapper](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_queried_object_id/) such that you needn't manually reference the `$wpdb` global yourself.

Comment: thanks. It had me at my wits end. Would you recommend that `$post_id = get_the_ID();` is sufficient and the rest of the code is superfluous?

Comment: It really depends on the use-case. `get_the_ID()` by itself is sufficient for retrieving the current post ID within The Loop, but if you need to know the ID of a single-post request anywhere else (i.e. `template_redirect`, header template file, for use in some secondary query, etc.) then you'll probably still need `get_queried_object_id()` in some form. IMO, I feel like the two use-cases are distinct enough that it probably usually doesn't make a lot of sense to try and cover them both with one general function, however

Comment: Thanks. That's super helpful to know. Be keen to pick your brains more if that's okay - https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138624/wordpress